# spaCy SPECIAL-1 token overriding suffix rule causing annotation misalignment

Tags: python, tokenize, spacy, rules

My text is like

```
'Laboratories, Inc.'
```

Which gets tokenized like

```
Laboratories     TOKEN
,    SUFFIX
Inc.     SPECIAL-1
```

However annotations usually don't include suffix characters like '.'

So I tried adding a suffix rule to tokenize the '.'

```
(r'[.]+$',)
```

But it does not work for strings like  'Inc.' or 'St.' which are tagged as SPECIAL-1
The problem is this and tokenization issue like this cause a substantial amount of annotations to be ignored due to these misalignment issue, significantly reducing valuable examples during training.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: @smci but the square brackets represent a character class so the dot is being treated as such, the regex reads 'one or more period characters at the end of a string', I'm pretty sure that's what it does, you can test it for yourself here https://regex101.com/

Comment: erotavlas: sorry, you're right. Inside a character class/ square brackets, `[.]` is not magic. (As it happens I've been debugging spaCy regexes and tokenization a lot recently, and I get paranoid about overly broad bits, like dot `.` outside `[...]`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tokenizer exceptions (also: special cases, rules) have priority over the other patterns, so you would need to remove the special cases you don't want.

`nlp.tokenizer.rules` contains the special cases, which you can modify. Remove all exceptions with periods, as an example:

```
new_rules = {}
for orth, exc in nlp.tokenizer.rules.items():
    if "." not in orth:
        new_rules[orth] = exc
nlp.tokenizer.rules = new_rules
```

Comment: do you mean `if "." not in exc`?  Also this did not work for me, I added this block of code after the code blocks that modify the infix, suffix and prefix. those strings are still being flagged as SPECIAL-1 when I run the explain() method

Comment: I think we need to do something like this https://spacy.io/usage/adding-languages#tokenizer-exceptions except not sure how to do the import from util

Comment: Should be `if "." not in orth`, fixed above!

Comment: This is a one-liner if you use a dict comprehension with an if-clause: `nlp.tokenizer.rules = {k:v for k,v in nlp.tokenizer.rules.items() if '.' not in orth}`